# Render Vue.js @click directive outside of html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a link set up like so:

```
<a href="#" @click="modal=true">Open modal</a>
```

And here's the data:

```
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            modal: false
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a workaround to trigger the click event, without actually having to place the @click directly in the tag? The expected result would be the same however the @click would be defined elsewhere in the vue instance.

Comment: use vanilla event listeners?

Comment: I'd be interested in learning how a vanilla event binding would gain access to the data model variable.

Comment: are you allowed to use `ref=`  in the anchor's attribute ? If yes please find my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      modal: false
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    var self = this;
    this.$el.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function () {
        Vue.set(self, 'modal', true);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben i used a similar approach by creating a method, then triggering it with an eventListener in mounted()

Comment: I guess my answer is very similar to this so didn't post. But, I'd do `this.$refs.<ref-name>.$el.addEventList..()` and just `self.modal = true`. `Vue.set(...)` can be excluded since `modal` is already an attribute in `data`.